# Communicating Details on Demand Interaction Pattern: Consumer World Examples?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

I need to educate some development teams about "details on demand" - an interaction pattern where the user requests additional information about an object if necessary (as opposed to the system progressively disclosing it). The Wylie example isn't that compelling. Are the strong examples from the consumer web world that you would refer student to? Any favourites?

I am operating in an enterprise methodology space, so dashboards, table rows, procurement (ecommerce) examples would be perfect.

Comment: Jenifer Tidwell gives you three examples in her first edition of "Designing Interfaces": http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Extras_On_Demand

Answer (score 3):

On Twitter you can "expand" a tweet to get more info:
[image]

---

In the StackExhange network [you can see vote counts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) when you have > 1000 rep:
[image]

---

And you can get help to the comments fields:
[image]

---

And you can get additional information by hovering a user or a tag:
[image]

---

... just to mention a few web based solutions ;-)